# Within JSON string I have text variables with "quotes" giving JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 1712398

Tags: python, json

```
Example of data = [{"name":"Jamie Andersen","role":"Head of Laboratory "Synthestech" ","photo":""},{"name":"freddie nelof","role":"some text","photo":""},///]
```

The actual data is made from API and contains a lot a data so it's not manageable manually.

Quotes within a text variable like "Synthestech" in this examples makes the json file unreadable and gives error code:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 1712398.
```

My code is currently:

```
with open("C:/xampp/htdocs/code/data.json") as f:
    
    data_fuld = json.load(f)

df1 = pd.json_normalize(data_fuld)
#print(df1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
```

EDIT:
it is allways the same variable causing trouble, so maybe it's possibly to delete it before it is read as json, since i do not need the variable "role"?

Comment: It's simply **not** JSON. You need to fix it upstream.

Comment: well if i do a test run with a subset without the text quotes it works fine loading it as json

Comment: per @jonrsharpe, validating the sample JSON you provided via https://jsonlint.com/ shows the errors with the JSON.

Comment: nice page gives good clarity, but is it fixable?

Comment: "*is it fixable?*" As @jonrsharpe's comment mentions, "You need to fix it upstream." Any standards-compliant parser will not be able to parse this data. The API you're getting this data from is simply not serializing this data correctly. Even if you were to shoehorn a solution in for this one particular case, there are more likely than not other similar issues with this datasource which will crop up and will turn your maintenance into a nightmarish game of a whack-a-mole.

Comment: Yes, because without the test quotes it _is_ valid JSON. You need to fix whatever is emitting this and claiming it's JSON.

Comment: I assume that "Example of data = " is something you added and the `data.json` file is literally what you posted... In that case, get rid of your editorial part, it makes the question more confusing. Is this exactly what comes from the API? In that case, its broken. Has there been any other processing before it was saved to the `data.json` file?

Comment: the data file is as the example given within the brackets [...] just with more variables and observation. it's made in php using https://foundico.com/developers/ API. it's then saved as json.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to fix the upstream api so that it actually produces valid data.

Alternatively you can inspect the JSONDecodeError and try to fix the input data by escaping the `"` characters. This is a very hacky solution, and only work on a specific kind of wrong json.

```
import re, json

def parse(data):
    try:
        return json.loads(data)
    except json.JSONDecodeError as err:
        if not err.msg == "Expecting ',' delimiter":
            raise
        # insert a `\` before the last `"` in front of the syntax error position
        escaped_data = re.sub(r'^(.*)"', r"\1\"", data[:err.pos]) + data[err.pos:]
        return parse(escaped_data)
```

Comment: did not solve it sadly.